# How to select different database row base on which radio button selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am currently doing a bank project which I could select the months of transaction history I want to view ( Eg: Current Month, Current Month n last 1 month ) Now, I only manage to retrieve all the transaction history I had using grid view. May I know how to view transactions for different period based on the radio button selected? I'm currently using asp.net n C#

```
  myConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut from [Transaction]", myConnection);

    myConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = reader1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: No one has the idea how your radio button values look like. But you can use WHERE clause in your query. `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE thDate BETWEEN '2012/01/01' AND '2012/07/01'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your SQL command you could try:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut from [Transaction] where thDate=" + RadioButtonList1.Text + ", myConnection);
```

Where `RadioButtonList1` is replaced by the name of your RadioButtonList. This should place the value of the selected radio button into the SQL statement.

Comment: You need to create SqlConnection prior to this.

Comment: @nvrtheless I know that but I was working with the information provided, and by the sounds of it the connection has already been established as they are already able to retrieve all the details and they wanted help to narrow down the search